# How to find the number of iterations of binary search algorithm?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, binary-search

How I can get the number of iterations of binary search?

This is my code:

```
int main() 
{
    int target = 11;
    int N = 10;
    std::vector<int> index;
    int num;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        index.push_back(i);
    }

    int counter = 0;
    unsigned int M, L = (unsigned int)-1, R = N;

    M = (R - L) / 2;  // Assume N is not zero

    do {
        int value;
        M = M + L;
        value = index[M];
        if (value < target) L = M; else R = M;
        M = (R - L) / 2;
        counter++;
    } while (M);  // M is the size of the current interval

    std::cout << R << '\n';
    std::cout << "counter: " << counter << '\n';

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

I want to know the number of iterations depending on `N`.
I know how this algorithm works but I want the number of iterations 
represented mathematically.

Comment: Since you know how the algorithm works, you know that each iteration halves the search area. You can perform successive divisions until you reach a search area of 1 with a variety of input N, plot the N versus the number of iterations and pick the curve that best fits, or you can short-circuit the curve-fitting step by already knowing which mathematical operation performs successive divisions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go for a recursive increment of by using a recursive binary search function.
In each branch of the binary checks, just increment by one and that will count the iterations recursively.

[See live here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/kJsQFsHJDsHjI6Jq)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::size_t binarySearch(
    const std::vector<int>& arr,        // pass array as non-modifiyable(const ref)
    std::size_t start, std::size_t end, // start and end indexes of the array
    const int target)                   // target to find
{
    if (arr.size() == 1) return arr[0] == target ? 1 : 0; // edge case

    if (start <= end)
    {
        const std::size_t mid_index = start + ((end - start) / 2);
        return arr[mid_index] == target ? 1 :                         // found the middle element
               arr[mid_index] < target ?
                 binarySearch(arr, mid_index + 1, end, target) + 1:   // target is greater than mid-element
                 binarySearch(arr, start, mid_index - 1, target) + 1; // target is less than mid-element
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int target = 11;
    const int N = 10;
    std::vector<int> index;
    index.reserve(N); // reserve some memory
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        index.push_back(i);
    }
    std::cout << "counter: " << binarySearch(index, 0, index.size() - 1, target) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**:

```
counter: 4
```

Answer (score 2):

Mathematically Maximum iteration possible (Assuming case of only integer type) is  = ceil( log2 ( initial_r - initial_l ) ) base of log is 2 because every time we are diving our range in half by taking a mid and switching to one of the half.

Comment: Could you elaborate the idea with an example, if possible?

Answer (score 1):

I have been trying to wrap my head around the logarithmic conceptualization too, and this is how I try to understand the answer

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm

> In mathematics, the binary logarithm (log<sub>2</sub>n) is the power to which
> the number 2 must be raised to obtain the value n. That is, for any
> real number x, 
> x=log<sub>2</sub>n <=equivalent to=>
> 2<sup>x</sup>=n

&

> Every binary tree with n leaves has height at least log<sub>2</sub>n, with equality when n is a > power of two and the tree is a complete binary tree.

Binary search is kind of like walking down a binary search tree, and halving the nodes, and that series is a logarithmic (base 2) series
<sub>(my own understanding, no citation, can be erroneous)</sub>

And then from [https://www.cct.lsu.edu/~sidhanti/tutorials/data_structures/page305.html](https://www.cct.lsu.edu/%7Esidhanti/tutorials/data_structures/page305.html)

> a perfect binary tree of height h has exactly 2<sup>h+1</sup>-1
> internal nodes. Conversely, the height of a perfect binary tree with n
> internal nodes is log<sub>2</sub>(n+1). If we have a search tree
> that has the shape of a perfect binary tree, then every unsuccessful
> search visits exactly h+1 internal nodes, where
> h=log<sub>2</sub>(n+1).

<sub>(again following up with my own understanding...)</sub>
So, to reach a node N (with value N as per binary search tree?), you would make log<sub>2</sub>(N+1) iterations (traverse that many levels down the tree) in worst case (finding is still a probability, hence "worst case" phrasing).

Dry run here (by constructing a small BST and counting manually): [https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/BST.html](https://www.cs.usfca.edu/%7Egalles/visualization/BST.html)

<sub>(answer open for review/confirmations/corrections in phrasing/calculations too ofcourse as I am trying to consolidate different resources to reach a theory that makes sense in this context)</sub>